# Java Time Zone When Parsing DateFormat

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, date-format, iso8601

I had code that parses date as follows:

```
String ALT_DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    ALT_DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
Date date = sdf.parse(requiredTimeStamp);
```

And it was working fine, suddenly, this stopped working. It turns out an admin made some config changes on the server and the date is currently being returned as "2010-12-27T10:50:44.000-08:00" which is not parse-able by the above pattern. I have two questions:

The first would be what pattern would parse the date being returned by the JVM in the format above (specifically, just '-08:00' as the time zone)? And second, where exactly would one change such settings on a linux RHEL 5 server so that we are aware of such changes in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other application is using the ISO 8601 dateTime format. I am assuming the other application is sending you an XML response that is in compliance with XML Schema's dateTime type, which is ISO 8601. Now, it is a known thing that the DateFormat can't parse this format. You either have to use other libraries like joda-time (joda-time is the winner) or the FastDateFormat as specified in the other responses. Look at this post [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: The Joda-Time library works but is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.

Answer (score 33):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2010-12-27T10:50:44.000-08:00" )
```

## ISO 8601

The input string format is defined in the [ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4542679/642706) standard, a family of date-time formats.

## Avoid old date-time classes

The Question and other Answers use old outmoded date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Avoid them. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Using java.time

Your input string ends with an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). So we parse as a [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2010-12-27T10:50:44.000-08:00" );
```

If you want to view this date-time value as a moment on the timeline in UTC, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
```

A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). If you have a time zone in mind, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. Same moment on the timeline, but viewed through a different [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z );  // Same moment on the timeline, but viewed through a different wall-clock time.
```

[image]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

if still looking for answer, this worked for me

My Input : **2020-12-08T10:36:53.939+05:30**
My Output : **Tue Dec 08 10:36:53 IST 2020**

You can convert this date to any format you need !

```
private static Date convertDate(String input) {
    Date newDate = null;
    try {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        newDate=dateFormat.parse(input);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse it using straight JDK, i believe it should be parseable using the JAXB utils, see [DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar%28java.lang.String%29) or [DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

### Use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/%E2%80%8E)

As a more concrete example to @Pangea's suggestion to use JodaTime, this is what you could use:

```
String timestamp = "2012-09-17T04:11:46Z";

DateTime date = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseDateTime(timestamp);
```

This correctly recognizes the UTC timezone. I haven't tried it with milliseconds in the string timestamp, but I'm confident it'll work just as well.

Hope that helps others.

JP

Comment: FYI: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for pointing that out! If using Java SE 8+, they recommend moving over to `java.time`. Happy to see these improvements are being brought into the core.

Comment: Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Further adapted for Android in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

Comment: FYI, all these projects ([Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), [JSR 310](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), and [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/)) are led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

- OffsetDateTime (inbuilt in Java 8)
- [joda](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html) (the all mighty of dates - a 3rd party library)

> OffsetDateTime is clearly a better option here, but if joda has been proven to be quite powerful from quite some time now and if someone prefers to use that then below code has sample of both

Code Sample of both approaches are given below:

```
public class Demo {
public static void jodaTimeStuff(String dateString, DateTimeZone dtz) {
    System.out.println(StringUtils.leftPad(dateString, 29, " ") + "\t------->\t" + ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(dateString).toDateTime(dtz));
    System.out.println(StringUtils.leftPad(dateString, 29, " ") + "\t------->\t" + OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString).toZonedDateTime());
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    jodaTimeStuff("2010-03-01T08:00:00.000Z", DateTimeZone.UTC);
    jodaTimeStuff("2010-03-01T08:00:00.000Z", DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")));
    jodaTimeStuff("2010-03-01T00:00:00.000-08:00", DateTimeZone.UTC);
    jodaTimeStuff("2010-03-01T00:00:00.000-08:00", DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")));
    jodaTimeStuff("2010-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30", DateTimeZone.UTC);
    jodaTimeStuff("2010-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30", DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")));
    jodaTimeStuff("2021-11-15T02:27:24.540288Z", DateTimeZone.UTC);
    jodaTimeStuff("2021-11-15T02:27:24.540288Z", DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")));
}
```

}

Output:

```html
     2010-03-01T08:00:00.000Z   ------->    2010-03-01T08:00:00.000Z
     2010-03-01T08:00:00.000Z   ------->    2010-03-01T08:00Z
     2010-03-01T08:00:00.000Z   ------->    2010-03-01T13:30:00.000+05:30
     2010-03-01T08:00:00.000Z   ------->    2010-03-01T08:00Z
2010-03-01T00:00:00.000-08:00   ------->    2010-03-01T08:00:00.000Z
2010-03-01T00:00:00.000-08:00   ------->    2010-03-01T00:00-08:00
2010-03-01T00:00:00.000-08:00   ------->    2010-03-01T13:30:00.000+05:30
2010-03-01T00:00:00.000-08:00   ------->    2010-03-01T00:00-08:00
2010-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30   ------->    2010-02-28T18:30:00.000Z
2010-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30   ------->    2010-03-01T00:00+05:30
2010-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30   ------->    2010-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30
2010-03-01T00:00:00.000+05:30   ------->    2010-03-01T00:00+05:30
  2021-11-15T02:27:24.540288Z   ------->    2021-11-15T02:27:24.540Z
  2021-11-15T02:27:24.540288Z   ------->    2021-11-15T02:27:24.540288Z
  2021-11-15T02:27:24.540288Z   ------->    2021-11-15T07:57:24.540+05:30
  2021-11-15T02:27:24.540288Z   ------->    2021-11-15T02:27:24.540288Z
```

Some dependencies used in the sample code (one is just for formatting and another one is for joda:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

> Dua me yaad rakhna (Please remember me in your prayers)

Answer (score 0):

The question should be where `requiredTimeStamp` is coming from and in which format. Is it entered by a user, or read from another program? Which component creates the date in the String representation?

The format "2010-12-27T10:50:44.000-08:00" looks like standardized format [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
It should be parseable with the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Not sure which settings affect this, but there is an [Oracle FAQ about Java TimeZones](http://crmondemand.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/dst-faq-138158.html).
It may be `user.timezone` system property or the `/etc/localtime` symlink in RHEL.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. requiredTimeStamp is generated by a java application on the server (not ours) and sent as part of a service response. It seems to be using some default server setting since it changes with server reconfiguration. The timestamp '-08:00' is not parse-able by Z in the pattern even in an isolated unit test on my machine, Z can parse '-0800' or 'GMT-08:00' but not '-08:00'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to lower case z.

z processes most of the common general timezone syntax, while Z uses stricter RFC 822 time zone with 4 digits.

Although its documented that both should parse 'General timezone settings', it might make the difference in your case.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat only accepts `-0800` or `GMT-08:00` as the timezone.

It seems the ISO 8601 format can not be parsed with `SimpleDateFormat`. Maybe you should have a look at [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)'s [FastDateFormat](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat.html). It is compatible with `SimpleDateFormat` but accepts the `ZZ` pattern for the timezone that should parse the timezone format you need. [DateFormatUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateFormatUtils.html) contains some example constants that look like the pattern you need, just without the milliseconds (for example [ISO_DATETIME_TIME_ZONE_FORMAT](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateFormatUtils.html#ISO_DATETIME_TIME_ZONE_FORMAT)).

Comment: As far as I could tell, FastDateFormat doesn't support parsing.

Comment: Seems you are right. Since it implements the standard Format interface I assumed that it would also parse the format like SimpleDateFormat. I didn't check the comments for the parse methods.